# Passing an array through localStorage into a new array not working as intended

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, local-storage

This is quite a long, complicated and specific question, but I am hoping someone can help, because I cannot seem to find the reason/logic to crack it.

**Note** I know that I am using deprecated mysql, but this is not where the problem is (plus my hosting site only supports older versions)

Part 1 is `dataLoader.php` -> this script queries the database. From the tables it gets we have `posx` and a `posy` for each row in the table. These are then being sent via localStorage to another page - `download.php`. This is the relevant code from `dataLoader.php`:

```html
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var xPos = [];
  var yPos = [];
</script>
<?php //*Connect to database* 
$locationq = "SELECT posx, posy FROM locations";
$locationrs = mysql_query($locationq) or die ('Couldnt get location'.mysql_error());
while ($locrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($locationrs))
{
 echo " | " .$locrow['posx'] . " | " . $locrow['posy'];
 $posx = $locrow['posx'];
 $posy = $locrow['posy'];
 echo "<input type ='hidden' class='posx' name='posx' value='$posx' >";
 echo "<input type ='hidden' class='posy' name='posy' value='$posy' ><br>";
 echo "<script> xPos.push($('.posx').val());  yPos.push($('.posy').val()); 
 </script>";
}
echo  "<script>localStorage.setItem('xPos',xPos); 
  localStorage.setItem('yPos',yPos);</script>";
echo $posx;
echo $posy;
exit; 
mysql_close(); ?>
</body>


</html>
```

Part 2 is the `download.php` where the data(coords) from `dataLoader.php` is taken and drawn onto a google maps map. **THE PROBLEM IS** that when i check the localStorage (using f12) it has the values of the first row twice, instead of having 2 different sets of values.

**The bit that puzzles me** is that it only stores the values of the first team in the database table and not the second. My trouble is getting both posx and posy for every row in the table and then for every posx and posy put a marker on the map. The values are being displayed by the echo (different values for both rows), but in the localStorage it is only the value of the first row.

For some reason, however, I am having trouble passing in the values of the second table row.

- Surely if anything I should be getting the values of the last row and not the first since the loop is running through at least once, but all I seem to get is the data from that first loop. Hopefully this all makes sense and thanks in advance.

  - In the screenshot you can see the echo output on the left and the values stored in the localstorage, which do not correspond.

[image: You can see that it is not storing the second value, even though it is looping through]

Comment: What does the HTML/Javascript the browser sees look like for downloader.php?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I have edited it, hopefully my issue is a bit clearer now.

Comment: have you checked returtning values out of the loop by echoing the screen

Comment: I tried it and the echo is displaying the values of the second row, while in storage it still has the value of the first row twice... I edited the OP, because I thought maybe I need to be storing the arrays only once they are full, but that hasn't helped either

Comment: I will attach a screenshot to illustrate the problem more clearly in a sec

Comment: well i just cant get the point theres a while loop and here it pushes into your array whatever your php returns the problem i guess is in  your php script

Comment: if you look at the screenshot i just added you will see that it is only storing the first values in the localStorage and not the second, even though it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler than expected all I needed to do was `echo "<script> xPos.push($posx);  yPos.push($posy);</script>";`